# Copy one matrix into a column of another

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create a matrix whose columns contain the data of the rows of other matrices. My compiler is telling me, though, that there's no such function as `Mat::copyTo(Mat)` even though it's [in the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto) and my IDE autocompletes it (meaning it's in the header and the header is included).

```
binary.row(selectedRow).reshape(1).copyTo(data.col(0));
reduced.row(selectedRow).reshape(1).copyTo(data.col(1));
```

Any ideas at all why this fails? I'm fed up with the `InputArray`/`OutputArray` style of OpenCV, I wish they'd just match the method signatures to what's actually expected instead of relying on compiletime/runtime errors.

**Edit:** I know I could just run a `for` loop and copy the data and be done with it, but there should be a simple way to do this using OpenCV methods.

**Edit2:** here's the actual error:

```
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1651:10: note: void cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::OutputArray) const
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1651:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'cv::Mat' to 'cv::OutputArray {aka const cv::_OutputArray&}'
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1653:10: note: void cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray) const
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1653:10: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: What's the error, exactly?

Comment: Did you tell your compiler where to search for header files?  Did you tell your compiler about other header files?

Comment: Did you try *reading* the doc you linked? `CopyTo` doesn't take a `Mat` as an argument; it takes an `OutputArray`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My project indeed includes OpenCV, and I know my IDE sees it because it autocompletes the method, which it won't do if the file hasn't been linked properly. Should be in `<opencv2/core/core.hpp>` but that's already been `#include`d. I'm using all the other core features of OpenCV with no problems and have been using them extensively for months. This is why I'm completely baffled by this.

Comment: @WhozCraig that's how all the OpenCV documentation works. `InputArray` and `OutputArray` can be `std::vector<double>`, `std::vector<cv::Mat>`, `cv::Mat`, or even `cv::Vec3d` depending on context. Hence my expressed frustration at the bottom of my question. Trust me, I've been *reading* these docs for months.

Comment: @RyanMuller OK. I see, and my apologies. Looking at the error, is it possible the `data.col(0)` and `data.col(1)` are returning **`const`**  references? This would make the error message make much more sense, as (a) it is not two parameters, so the second prototype obviously can't match, and (b) by the prototype for `copyTo()` the single-param version requires a non-const parameter. The error seems to indicate `data.col(n)` is returning a `const` reference, and thus, no match. Sorry I don't know CV worth marbles, but I know the language very well, and thats what it looks like to me.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're a genius! That is indeed what happened. I defined a `currentColumn = data.col(i)` and passed that to `copyTo()`. Submit this as an answer and I'll accept it... thanks!

Comment: @RyanMuller I'm glad it works. Its kind of a bummer, to have to use that intermediate object. I can see what you *wanted* to do and i would indeed be nice if it could be done in-place. Ah well. I'll post something so you can resolve an answer. Glad it halped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the returned error message, neither of the possible allowable overrides of `copyTo()` appear to be a good match.

The two-parameter override obviously isn't going to work. The single parameter override appears to need a non-const reference as the copy target (which certainly makes sense when thinking about it). That said, `data.col(0)` and `data.col(1)` appear to be returning const references, which aren't writable and therefore not a good match either.

You may have to use an intermediate object, then a setter for your data columns, unless `data` can return a writable reference to the object you desire to be your target of the copy.

Best of luck.